# In OpenGL can I access the buffer I'm drawing in a vertex shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, opengl-es, vbo

I know that each time a vertex shader is run it basically accesses part of the buffer (VBO) being drawn, when drawing vertex number 7 for example it's basically indexing 7 vertices into that VBO, based on the vertex attributes and so on.

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 texCoords;     // This may be running on the 7th vertex for example.
```

What I want to do is have access to an earlier part of the VBO for example, so when it's drawing the 7th Vertex I would like to have access to vertex number 1 for example, so that I can interpolate with it.

Seeing that at the time of running the shader it's already indexing into the VBO already, I would think that this is possible, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: You can bind the vbo as an ssbo and access it from the shader, but this is not pratical. What's the larger scope of your question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pleluron I have a large grid of vertices which represents a terrain, and many of the vertices have another vertex in the grid as a morph target that it interpolates with so that level of detail transition is smooth. At the moment I have my vertex attribute layout as position, morphTargPosition, normal, morphTargNormal, texCoords, morphTargCoords - basically doubled up everything. It's actually working better than I thought, but obviously it's a terrible waste of space like this.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation, vertex attributes are expected to change on every shader run. So no, you can't access attributes defined for other vertices in a vertex shader.

You can probably do this:
Define a uniform array and pass in the values you need. But keep in mind that you are using more memory this way, you need to pass more data etc.

Comment: @Titone Maurice No, I don't think so. You can use the same shader with both VBOs/local arrays but you can't even distinguish between them in the shader, so OpenGL probably treats them much like the same thing but data is just in different places.

Answer (score 0):

As @Reaper said you can use a uniform buffer, which can be accessed freely. But the GPU doesn't like random access, it's usually more efficient to stream the data.

You can solve this as well by just adding the data for later/earlier vertices into the array, because in C++ all vertices are at your disposal.

For example if this is the "normal" array:

```
{
    vertex1_x, vertex1_y, vertex1_z, normal1_x, normal1_y, normal1_z, texCoord1_x, texCoord1_y,
    ...
}
```

Then you could extend it with data for the other vertex to interpolate with:

```
{
    vertex1_x, vertex1_y, vertex1_z, normal1_x, normal1_y, normal1_z, texCoord1_x, texCoord1_y, vertex2_x, vertex2_y, vertex2_z, normal2_x, normal2_y, normal2_z, texCoord2_x, texCoord2_y,
    ...
}
```

Actually you can pass any data per vertex. Just make sure that the stride size and other parameters are adjusted in the glVertexAttribPointer parameters.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing at the moment, but it ends up doubling size of everything. Apart from the standard pos, norm and texCoords I may want to have tangents, and another UV channel, or whatever. Just seems really counterintuitive that the draw call is drawing the buffer but it can't access anything from it except for the vertex, or primitive. Even if I created another buffer and bound it as a uniform, why would I have to create another buffer if the buffer's already been loaded onto the GPU?

Comment: @TitoneMaurice: Yes, if you have a uniform buffer you would still need to "draw" another buffer, which contains the "IDs" (index numbers) of the vertices, so the shaders know which is the current vertex. And if your terrain is big, then you can have problems, because on today's GPUs the max uniform buffer size is around 64 KBytes.

Comment: Actually I have another idea. Don't stream duplicate data, but instead of that just define local arrays inside the shaders. As you draw, you store there the current vertex, but only keep data for the last 10 (or so) vertices. For this to work, you just have to make sure to keep close the vertices which might morph into each other. (keep them in a fixed distance) In this way you would use minimal local memory.

Comment: Sounds interesting. How do you write to the array as you're drawing vertices? The only time I've done something like this is transform feedback, basically I did a draw call and each time the vertex shader ran it wrote a value to an array, which I then pulled from my C++ code.

Comment: The simplest would be a circular buffer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer You don't even need to maintain the start/end pointers. Just extend the vertex data "record" with a  new "vertex_index" field, which would contain the number of the vertex. In the shader you would cast it to integer. You would need an array per property which you want to store. If the circular buffer is 16 elements long, then you calculate vertex_index % 16 (division remainder) to get current position (where to write to). You would only interpolate if vertex_index > 16. Then:

Comment: Then if the interpolating vertex is (for example) 12 elements away, you can get its index by: (vertex_index - 12) % 16

Comment: I did some investigation and this would not work. In the GPU there are multiple units working parallel on the vertex data. They have their own local registers, and they get different vertices. So still 2 solutions exist, the uniform buffer (stateful solution) or the data duplication (stateless solution).

Comment: I appreciate all your help. I'm finding all this stuff hard. There are quite a few restrictions when programming shaders, I hope I find a good way to do this.